# How do I get Tokenization key in Woocommerce Rest API?

Tags: android, ios, paypal, woocommerce, braintree

We are using the Woocommerce Rest API for the Mobile Application Development like Android And IOS. We have integrated the payment method as Braintree using the plugin [WooCommerce PayPal Powered by Braintree Payment Gateway](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-powered-by-braintree/).

It is working fine on our website but the Mobile applications need the client token or Tokenization key for integrating the Braintree SDKs.

This plugin does not store any Tokenization key or Client Token in our database so how will give it in APIs for Integration? It stores Only merchant id in woocommerce Braintree settings.

So, How we will Integrate the Braintree Payment Gateway on the website and mobile application using WooCommerce REST API.

Please suggest if anyone have Idea...

Answer (score 2):

**[To obtain a tokenization key](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/authorization/tokenization-key/android/v2):**

1. Log into either the production Control Panel or the sandbox Control Panel, depending on which environment you are working in
2. Navigate to **Settings -> API Keys**

You should see your key under the **Tokenization Keys** section. If no key appears, click **Generate New Tokenization Key**. Copy this key.

---

**To use this tokenization key in your android app:**

1. Place the key (copied after the above steps) in your `/res/values/strings.xml`
2. In your code, get the key from your string resources you just placed in the above step.
3. Supply this key as the 2nd parameter when initializing braintree using `BraintreeFragment.newInstance(activity, tokenizationKey);`

Comment: Thanks for the Replay, May, you haven't got my point we are using the WooCommerce REST API so, we will set our Braintree account details on the server only. we don't want to save anything on APP side. So, If anything changes on the server ( website ) then we also get the latest details.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but the tokenizationKey is in fact supposed to be placed inside the app. This is a way to identify which app is trying to access the REST API. After all it is your app that will be calling the api.

Comment: If you insist that you have a (proxy) server that calls the rest api, then you could place the same tokenizationKey as a constant in yout server side code.

Comment: Yes. But if admin changes the Braintree account details on our website without updating to the app developer then it is completely wrong.

Comment: Yes, Constant is the better suggestion.

Comment: TokenizationKey stays the same in case of changes in the braintree account. It will only change if you replace the whole account, and you'll likely never have to do that. You should not have to do that.
The constant suggestion is only if you have a server thst acts as a proxy between braintree api and the app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161979/discussion-between-mr-ajay-and-abdul-wasae).